# Comparing a Core Data date to a Swift Date in a FetchRequest

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to fetch entries that are less than a particular date. In my FetchRequest I'm saying:

```
let theDatePredicate = NSPredicate(format:"libCompInGameCreationDate < %@",latestDate as CVarArg)
```

Where `libCompInGameCreationDate` is a date field in my Core Data entity and `latestDate` is a `Date` type. It's running, but it delivers all of my data – the comparison doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: It should work. You could avoid the as `CVarArg` with `argumentArray:`. Could you show one record (that shouldn't be there) and `latestDate`?

Comment: Or cast it to NSDate instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. I'll keep looking.